# INFO - Started Jetty Server, but does not finish

Tags: java, apache, maven, jetty, http-status-code-503

I am trying to setup Dashbuilder.  I have worked through a couple issues already (one with the help of others here, thank you).  I am at the point where the program must be compiled, built, and run using command

```
./buildandrun.sh h2
```

things start off as expected, but then just stop at "[INFO] Started Jetty Server" in terminal.

I've let it sit for hours, no progress.  I tried running with the -X flag, but no extra info for that step appeared.  When I try to visit http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder to see if the program started I get a 503 error and see

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /dashbuilder. Reason:
>
> ```
> Service Unavailable
> ```
>
> Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.9.v20160517

How can I see in better detail what and why something like this is happening?

Contents of the SH file are:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "" ] ; then
   echo "Build & Run the application for a given database."
   echo ""
   echo "USAGE: buildandrun.sh [h2|postgres]"
else
  echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
  echo "Building & Running the application for the '$1' database..."
  echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"

  cd ..
  mvn clean install -P $1,jetty  $2 $3 $4

  export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
  cd modules/dashboard-showcase/
  mvn jetty:run -P $1,jetty
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jetty:run` goal of the `jetty-maven-plugin` does exactly that.

It runs Jetty, normally, and waits for the user to terminate it (either with TERM, KILL, Ctrl+C, use of the Shutdown facilities)

That `mvn jetty:run` command never returns.

Perhaps you wanted to use `mvn jetty:start` and `mvn jetty:stop`

See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-start-goal