# Jenkins build should become success after starting jetty server, how to do this?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jetty

I am starting the jetty server from jenkins with "jetty:run" as maven goals. Server is started but my build never comes to an end. I had to abort the build manually. Is there a way to stop the server after lets say 2 or 3 mins and also my build should become success?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a timeout step to Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096004/how-to-add-a-timeout-step-to-jenkins-pipeline). To prevent timeout from marking build as aborted, catch exception using try / catch.

Comment: Answered before at [Started Jetty Server, but does not finish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37485430/775715)